# CoreGraphics printing weird message

Tags: ios, pdf, core-graphics, memory-leaks, instruments

I recently came to following debug messag, when I diplay some PDF files.

I think it occurs on some pages, when the CALayer redraws them.

```
Text clipping 0xab9b930:
 Node 0: XIXHYA+LinotypeFeltpen-Medium-OV-IFXHYA (31.0031, 0, 0, 31.0031, 29.5798, 137.483)
    14 (0, 0)
 Node 1: XIXHYA+LinotypeFeltpen-Medium-OV-IFXHYA (31.0031, 0, 0, 31.0031, 36.3075, 137.483)
    25 (0, 0)
 Node 2: XIXHYA+LinotypeFeltpen-Medium-OV-IFXHYA (31.0031, 0, 0, 31.0031, 49.7628, 137.483)
    12 (0, 0)
...
```

What does it mean?

Is it also possible, that there is an interconnection between memory leaks, because it occurs, that when the pages are displayed, it sometimes prints a memory warning. For a better understanding, I use Instruments on the Simulator to detect leaks, but it couldn't find anything. Only when I test the Application on an iPad, it prints this memory leak warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out, what the messages are meaning. I know, they occure, when a CALayer is drawing something, but anyhow it doesn't have to do something with CoreGraphics pdf leaking.

The leaks occure by my own.